# Pipe/redirect password into ssh for automatic login?

Tags: linux, ssh, io-redirection

I use ssh to connect to an account based on Kerberos. My Kerberos tickets are only valid for 24h and are not renewed every time I login. Instead they expire and when that happens, ssh keys can't be used for password-less logins since my home directory is not mounted on the shell server, and hence, sshd can't read my authenticated keys.

I don't really care about the security for this account, I only use it to open a tunnel to access an SMTP-server (that in itself requires secure authentication) and **therefore wonder if it is possible to somehow echo/pipe/redirect my password** (which, BTW, due to stupid password requirements is impossible to remember so I have to have it as a fixed entry in a clipboard manager) **into my ssh command so I don't have to enter it manually every time?**

```
ssh -l user host < password
```

Comment: This question has been (kind of) answered before.  see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223491/piping-a-password-located-in-a-file-to-the-ssh-command

Comment: I think your question is answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

Comment: I wonder if kerberos supports ssh key another way. As this seems like obnoxious behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH login with clear text password as a parameter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38737/ssh-login-with-clear-text-password-as-a-parameter) ... `-p "$(xclip -o)"`, or "If no option is given, sshpass reads the password from the standard input."